# Intellij Commit Hunk Checkbox not there

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I just tried 2018.2 EAP and I don’t see the checkboxes in my gutter for partial hunk commits.. And it’s not in the commit dialog box either.

There are no IDE exceptions, and the other new features mentioned here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/06/whats-new-in-intellij-idea-2018-2-eap-4/ seem to be present, e.g being able to delete a tag in log view.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: What EAP version do you use ("Help | About")?

Comment: It's version 2018.2

Comment: I have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50940948/6309) to reflect the completion of [IDEA-186988: "Allow commiting only specific lines"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186988)

Answer (score 2):

You can activate it under "Settings => General =>" Highlight modified lines in gutter "
But why that was placed so I can not say!

Answer (score 1):

July 2023: [issue IDEA-186988](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186988) is marked as completed (IDEA 2023.2)!

Official documentation: "[Select chunks and specific lines you want to commit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.2/commit-and-push-changes.html#select_chunks_in_commit_changes_dialog)"

[image: https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2023.2/partial_commit_dialog.png]

And:

[image: https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2023.2/include_line_to_commit.png]

---

2018-2019: Beside [issue IDEA-186988](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186988) (still pending, for adding specific lines), the new `add -p` feature seems to be [working only in a specific mode](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/#comment-433629):

> **Only works in “Side-by-side viewer” Diff mode**.
> Having to switch from convenient “Unified viewer” mode to inconvenient “Side-by-side” just for commit individual lines/hunks is… how to say… against the very idea of IntelliJ IDEA of being convenient, isn’t it?

The same page "[IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 EAP: Partial Git commits and more](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more)" includes [the comment](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/#comment-480528) from **Jurgis Pralgauskis** (March 2019, similar to [Christian M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9981405/christian-m)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57395766/6309)):

> On PyCharm 2018.3.5 (pro) this is not shown in commit dialog unless I enable :
>
> ```
> Settings->Editor->General: Highlight modified files in gutter
> ```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I'm not referring to specific lines, just the checkbox for entire hunks

Comment: Do you have any screenshot illustrating that feature?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/

Comment: I see (https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/#comment-423533)

Comment: Did you check the comment "Only works in “Side-by-side viewer” Diff mode. Having to switch from convenient “Unified viewer” mode to inconvenient “Side-by-side” just for commit individual lines/hunks is… how to say… against the very idea of IntelliJ IDEA of being convenient, isn’t it?" ?

Comment: Yes, I saw the comment, but I tried side-by-side and still could not see it. This is very puzzling...

Answer (score 1):

I was also missing the checkboxes in git diff today in 2022 and found, they are introduced by installing a plugin called "GitToolBox" in the Marketplace (Preferences->Plugins->click on "Marketplace"->Search for "GitToolBox".
After installing and restarting the IDE, checkboxes in git diff view when in commit-window are present.